# How to change the size of child elements with [position:absolute] inside a parent element with [position:relative]?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on some parent/child CSS code and is struggling to make the images smaller.

I have tried to change the size with [max-width] both in percentages and pixels but it didn't work. Trying to change the size in both the parent element [.entireWoman] and the 4 children elements didn't make any difference also.

```
<div class="entireWoman">

    <div id="Woman">
        <img src="../Portfolio/images/Woman.png" alt="Woman">
    </div>

    <div id="upperRotate">
        <img src="../Portfolio/images/Upper_arm.png" alt="Upper arm">
    </div>

    <div id="downRotate">
        <img src="../Portfolio/images/Down_arm.png" alt="Down arm">
    </div>

    <div id="handRotate">
        <img src="../Portfolio/images/Hand.png" alt="Hand">
    </div>

</div>
```

```
.entireWoman{
    animation: enter 5s;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-top:400px;
    margin-left:400px;
}

.entireWoman > #Woman {
    position: absolute;
    max-width:20%;
    height:auto;
    z-index: 2;
}

.entireWoman > #upperRotate{
    max-width:10%;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: 90% 90%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.entireWoman > #downRotate {
    max-width:10%;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin:99% 50%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:-150px;
}

.entireWoman > #handRotate {
    max-width:10%;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    transform-origin: 99% 50%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:-220px;
}
```

Overall I just want to make the images smaller but none of the way I tried work.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue you’re having is that the container div is obeying your size rules but the image itself isn’t, and it’s overflowing the div. Try adding a rule to limit images to 100%:

```css
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

---

In the snippet below notice that the *div* is the correct size, but the image extends beyond its boundary. If you set the image max-width to 100% it conforms accordingly.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.item1 {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

img {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

input:checked + #container img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>The red box is the div containing the image.</p>
<p>Check the box to set max image width to 100%.</p>
</div>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<div id="container">
  <div class="item1">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/300" />
  </div>
</div>
```